# Generating XMLs from an XSD file in IBM Integration Bus OR WebSphere Message Broker

Tags: xml, xsd, ibm-integration-bus

I have an **XSD** file specifying the schema for the corresponding XMLs. A **message set** has been created using this XSD in wmb (or IIB ) toolkit. I need to generate random **XML**s (with any kind of dummy data) using the XSD/Message Set. The only requirement is that the generated test xmls should be **valid** as per the XSD. I was wondering if there's any built-in node in IBM Integration Bus OR WebSphere Message Broker such as `Reset Content Descriptor` which can automatically create the required XMLs with dummy data.[image: Message Set created using XSD file]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any automated way of doing this in IIB. If you don't need to generate the XML on the spot, you could just create sample files using a tool.

Some commercial offerings that can do this are Oxygen XML Editor, Altova XMLSpy  and Visual Studio. Some free options are the Eclipse IDE, Intellij IDEA (there's a community edition) and below links:

http://xsd2xml.com/

http://xmlgrid.net/genXml.html

https://devutilsonline.com/xsd-xml/generate-xml-from-xsd

There's also an old [XML generator in Java](https://github.com/kohsuke/msv/tree/master/generator).

If you need to provide an XML in a node, maybe you can just pick a pre-generated one up from some resource like the file system or a message queue.